# A lot fewer versions picked in plone 4.1 goodpy as compared to plone 4.1rc3

Tags: plone, zope

Please can someone explain to me why there are a lot fewer versions picked for Plone 4.1 final on goodpy as for Plone 4.1rc3.  With Plone 4.1 final there are a lot of unpicked versions.  Most appear to be zope.* packages.

e.g. compare

http://good-py.appspot.com/release/plone/4.1rc3
and
http://good-py.appspot.com/release/plone/4.1

I use buildout.dumppickedversions to list unpicked versions and force all versions to be picked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This appears to be due to the Zope 2.13.8 and ZTK 1.0.3 entries being incorrectly entered into good-py. It should be fixed now.

Comment: Yes much better now.  Thanks!